# levelup: get() requires key and callback arguments - no Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, leveldb

levelup docs say claim that `get()`, `put()`, etc will return a Promise if called without a callback:
https://github.com/Level/levelup#promises

I have the following code:

```
    db.get(gameName).then(JSON.parse).then(
```

but my `then()` functions never get called.  The code runs without crashing but I get the following message in the console:

```
get() requires key and callback arguments
```

Am I missing something?  Maybe a dependency?  I am willing to wrap `get()` and `put()` in my own Promises but it seems silly to rewrite functionality like that if it's already there.

Comment: `get() requires key and callback arguments` - perhaps you have an older version of the library? - looking at NPM, level up version is 1.3.9 - looking at github, levelup is at 2.0.0rc1 - so I think that documentation may be for the next major release

Comment: Good to know.  I'm at `"level": "^1.6.0",` so maybe i should just roll my own for now.  I'm not keen on sitting and waiting for the next release.  Thanks.

Comment: You may be interested in bluebird's promisfyAll functionality http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html

Comment: why use bluebird when node has it's own promisfier as of 8.4? (or maybe 8.3)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [Jaromanda X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x) and [Greg Hornby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2020574/greg-hornby) for the tips.  Indeed, `levelup` does not include Promises yet.  But in the meantime, here's a solution using `promisify`, which is now native to node:

```
const dbNoPromise = levelup('./app-db');
const {promisify} = require('util');
const db = { get : promisify(dbNoPromise.get.bind(dbNoPromise)),
         put : promisify(dbNoPromise.put.bind(dbNoPromise)),
         del : promisify(dbNoPromise.del.bind(dbNoPromise)) };
```